Edit package.json settings at runtime
I'm trying to make testing new js code faster. (Similar to how in python you can just put every line of code through a repl as your writing it. Related question here)
I've figured out I can run my code I'm testing in a simple in node like this:
//api_test/root.js
import { getCompanySingleTable } from '../src/graphql/queries.js'
import { API } from 'aws-amplify'

console.log(getCompanySingleTable )

PS M:\source\AdvancedStorageSite> node ./api_test/root.js

...if I first change my package.json to have this:
//package.json
{
    type: "module"
}

I'm worried adding this parameter may affect my production code and it will be really annoying to constantly comment and uncomment it every time I want to test some code.  Is there a way to add this parameter to node at runtime, or hook into the package.json file before it's parsed?
